# second javascript not working on my contact form

Tags: javascript, function, contact-form-7

Ok, all, I have a few questions.

1. How can I have my total have a $ and how can I move up next to the word Total: ( so it will be side by side)
2. Once I get a total price, is there a way where I can divide it by 2 to get 1/2 of the price into another field called 'deposit' before copying that to add to another field called 'balance':
3. I cannot get the date fields to copy

To note this is where I found how to add up the radio buttons ( [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632331/php-or-html-form-with-radio-options-add-up-different-prices/))

This is what I have so far.

This is my form:

```
Session Date: <input type="text" name="field1" id="f1" /> 

 Session Type payment :
<input type="radio" name="sessiontypepayment" id="sessiontypepayment1" value="100.00" onclick="FnCalculate(this,'extrapeople');"> Mini Session $100.00
<input type="radio" name="sessiontypepayment" id="sessiontypepayment2" value="250.00" onclick="FnCalculate(this,'extrapeople');"> Full Session $250.00

Extra people  :
<input type="radio" name="extrapeople" id="extrapeople1" value="25.00" onclick="FnCalculate(this,'sessiontypepayment');"> 1 person $25.00
<input type="radio" name="extrapeople" id="extrapeople2" value="50.00" onclick="FnCalculate(this,'sessiontypepayment');"> 2 people $50.00
<input type="radio" name="extrapeople" id="extrapeople3" value="75.00" onclick="FnCalculate(this,'sessiontypepayment');"> 3 people $75.00
<input type="radio" name="extrapeople" id="extrapeople4" value="100.00" onclick="FnCalculate(this,'sessiontypepayment');"> 4 people $100.00


Total Amount: <div id="total"></div>

Deposit Amount:

Balance Amount:

balance due BY: <input type="text" name="field2" id="f2" />
```

This is my script what I have so far.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#f1").keyup(function(){
        var f2Text = $('#f2').val() + $(this).val();
        $('#f2').val(f2Text );
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
function FnCalculate(id,name)
{
     var total=0;
     if(document.getElementById(name+"1").checked == true)
     {
         total = parseInt(document.getElementById(name+"1").value);
     }
     if(document.getElementById(name+"2").checked == true)
     {
         total = parseInt(document.getElementById(name+"1").value);
     }
     total = total + parseInt(id.value);
     document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
</script>
```

I would really love help on this please.

Comment: `var f2Text = '$'+((+$('#f2').val())+(+$(this).val()));`

Comment: Thank you for the help with the total field, but may I ask you where do I place it please, I am new to javascripts.

Comment: Use `/2` to divide by two. Note that `.val()` returns a String, putting `+` in front of a String casts it to a Number in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to place them please.

Comment: Hold on, I didn't see all your problems or your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get rid of all the `onclick="FnCalculate(this,'xx');"` bits on your inputs.

Then replace your `<script>`s with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#f1").keyup(function() {
            $('#f2').val($(this).val());
        });
        var inputs = $('input[name="sessiontypepayment"], input[name="extrapeople"]');
        $(inputs).click(function() {
            var total = 0;
            $(inputs).filter(':checked').each(function() {
                total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
            })
            $('#total').html('$' + total);
            $('#deposit').html('$' + (total / 2));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unsure what you mean by "how can I move up next to the word Total" but I suspect changing `<div id="total"></div>` to `<span id="total"></span>` will solve your problem. Either that, or apply some css to the div:

```
#total {
    display: inline;
}
```

I added the calculation for the deposit, you'll need to add `<div id="deposit"></div>` to your page somewhere...

You will need jquery. Add this in between `<head>...</head>`:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: OMG that worked!  thank you, thank you, thank you! your a life saver I racked my brain for two weeks trying to figure this out. Now I have another problem I do not know how to copy this to the email form so I get a copy of it.  Thank You again.

Comment: I am but about to go to bed... wazzup

Comment: I need help again, but if you have to head for bed , I can wait till tomorrow

Comment: This comment thing is getting really long, better make a new question I'll find it tomorrow if nobody has helped you by then!

Comment: I cant it will not let me, but I had switched to  another one I had, called (Value of radio button copy to text field) I will be home around 5pm est tomorrow

Comment: here is the link to my post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564586/value-of-radio-button-copy-to-text-field/26577368#26577368)

Comment: RJdown you hear I need help again please.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have your defaults set to `checked='checked'` for HTML radio buttons that you want checked initially. I would put default text into `<div id='total'>$125.00</div>`, as well. You might as well use jQuery for what it's made for and not put Events into your HTML at all. `.val()` returns a String. To cast a String to an integer put `+` in front of it. To cast to a floating point Number use `parseFloat()`.

```
$(function(){
$('#f1,[name=sessiontypepayment],[name=extrapeople]').change(function(){      
  $('#total').text('$'+(parseFloat($('[name=sessiontypepayment]:checked').val())+parseFloat($('[name=extrapeople]:checked').val())).toFixed(2));
  $('#f2').val($('#f1').val());
});
});
```

To divide by 2 it's `/2`

As a newbie you should get into the practice of using external `<script src` so it will get cached into your Browser Memory, for faster load time when your Client revisits your site.

Comment: Did you test this? There's quite a few issues.

Comment: rjdown yes I test it I only get the total with the script I have